# bootstrap Как можно сделать такое расположение блоков?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как автоматически располагать блоки максимально по центру при помощи boostrap? Количество блоков каждый раз может быть разным. Как вообще называется такое расположение блоков? Максимум блоков в ширину должно быть 3. Вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А на малых экранах они должны выстраиваться по 1 вообще.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `display: flex` для расположения блоков таким образом. И выравнивайте с помощью `justify-content` и `align-items`. `bootstrap` делает данные операции с помощью строк(`row`) и колонок(`col`)

```css
.blocks {
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
}

.block {
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="blocks row w-100 justify-content-center">
  <div class="block col-3">1</div>
  <div class="block col-3">2</div>
  <div class="block col-3">3</div>
  <div class="block col-3">4</div>
</div>
```